# What is E(|0.5-X|) when X ~ B(2, 2)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

What is the expected value of |0.5-X| when X is following the beta distribution of the first kind(alpha=2, beta=2)?

The reason why I want to do is to compare the performance between normal quick sort and median-of-three quick sort.
Normal quick sort: pick up the first element as pivot
Median-of-three quick sort:  pick up the first, middle and end element and pick up the median of those, then take it as pivot.

## memo

Probability Density Function of B(2,2)

$$f(x)=cx^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1} = 6x(1-x)$$
$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) \,dx$$
$$E(|0.5-X|)=\int_{x=0}^{\frac12} (0.5-x)6x(1-x) \,dx  + \int_{x=\frac12}^{1} (x-0.5)6x(1-x) \,dx=0.1875$$

Comment: $0.1875........$

Comment: how did you induce?

Comment: Do you know how to illustrate the context readable and clear? You should learn to work with mathjax or latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just integrate the (symmetric) beta distribution between $0$ and $1/2$ (or from $1/2$ to $1$) to find $0.1875$.

$$\frac{\int\limits_{x=0}^{1/2} (x-.5) x (1-x)\ dx}{\int\limits_{x=0}^{1/2} x (1-x)\ dx} = .1875$$

Comment: Thank you very much! But could you explain why I can get E|0.5-X| by doing that and how to integrate...?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate this using the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) which states that 
for a function $g(X)$ of a random variable $X$: $$E[g(X)] = \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} g(X)f_X(x) dx$$

In your case $g(X) = \left|0.5-X\right|$